# mongodb Aggregate for already grouped distinct combination (grouping inside grouping)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using mongoDB in which I have collection of following format.

```
{name : x  city : AAA , status : active , radius : 1 }
{name : x  city : AAA , status : active , radius : 4  }
{name : x  city : AAA , status : inactive , radius : 7 }
{name : x  city : BBB , status : inactive , radius : 7 }
{name : Y  city : AAA , status : active , radius : 8 }
{name : Y  city : BBB , status : inactive , radius : 5 }
{name : Y  city : BBB , status : inactive , radius : 12 }
{name : Z  city : CCC , status : deleted , radius : 15 }
```

Now I want unique combination of **name** and **class** and for that combination also required a sub-grouping of active , inactive and deleted count for status field. thus the overall out-put report will be in below format

```
Name  City  total  Active  Inactive deleted 
 X     AAA    3     2       1         0
 X     BBB    1     0       1         0
 Y     AAA    1     1       0         0
 Y     BBB    2     0       2         0
 Z     CCC    1     0       0         1
```

As I am new to mongodb thus can any one suggest that is there any way to get the required output format using aggregate or any other method with minimal query ?

Comment: Do you mean *city* instead of *class*? If so, please edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You require simply one `$group` stage, grouping by name and city, and a conditional sum for each of the `active`, `inactive` and `deleted` fields. Then you add a `$project` stage at the end just to get the exact format you want.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        name: "$name",
        city: "$city"
      },
      total: { 
        $sum: 1 
      },
      active: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$status", "active" ] }, 1, 0 ]
        }
      },
      inactive: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$status", "inactive" ] }, 1, 0 ]
        }
      },
      deleted: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$status", "deleted" ] }, 1, 0 ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id.name",
      city: "$_id.city",
      total: "$total",
      active: "$active",
      inactive: "$inactive",
      deleted: "$deleted"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Superb use of `$cond` in the grouping targets.